# Retrieving single record from firebase while using refs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working with the node library `firebase` and I want to search for a single value by using database refs.

I've been able to search for every single record on the realtime-database by returning the ref itself from my `CharacterService`'s `getAll` method, but I can't seem to find a way to do it for jus a single record.

**Firebase (Configuration file)**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';
import config from '../config';

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase);

const database = firebase.database();

export default database;
```

**CharacterService**

```js
import firebase from 'config/firebase';

const db = firebase.ref('/character');

class CharacterService {
  getAll () {
    return db;
  }

  create (character) {
    return db.push(character);
  }

  update (key, value) {
    return db.child(key).update(value);
  }

  delete (key) {
    return db.child(key).remove();
  }

  deleteAll () {
    return db.remove();
  }
}

export default new CharacterService();
```

**Database records**

```json
{
  "character" : {
    "-MLEm-8ehLQ4repmeKtl" : {
      "age" : 36,
      "exp" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "toLvlUp" : 125,
        "total" : 0
      },
      "gender" : "Male",
      "level" : 1,
      "name" : "Aleksandr Brightwood"
    },
    "-MLEm-7fhLQ5rehltKjk" : {
      "age" : 22,
      "exp" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "toLvlUp" : 125,
        "total" : 0
      },
      "gender" : "Female",
      "level" : 1,
      "name" : "Sarah Autumn"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "a single record".  It would help if you show the relevant contents of your database and explain what you expect to get from it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added example data.

Comment: So, what are you trying to get from that?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm trying to get a single character (by its key if possible). Right now I can only get ALL the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly get a child node using its key.

```
const childRef = firebase.ref('/character').child(key);
```

Now you have a Reference you can use to get only the data under that nested child.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) for more information.